# Entity Framework ObjectContent AddObject

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I add a new entity to the ObjectContext but I dont save it,

```
this.ObjectContext.SsoContactMd.AddObject(contact);
```

But after the new entity is not in the SspoContactMd collection.

Where can I find the entity that I added to collection?

regards, l.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SspoContactMd` is not a collection. It is `ObjectSet` = access point to the database. Every query you run on the `SspoContactMd` is converted to SQL and executed in the database. Because you didn't save your object you cannot get it back from the database.

If you want to find your object you must search for it in `ObjectStateManager`

```
var entity = this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager
                               .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
                               .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship)
                               .Select(e => e.Entity)
                               .OfType<YourContactType>()
                               .SingleOrDefault(c => ...);
```